# Constructor and prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading a snippet of code that defines a constuctor

```
var Resource = function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
}
```

and then subsequently defines a method to it.

```
Resource.query = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
}
```

Can I ask how this works? I know functions are objects as well, and is this the equivalent of the following? But if so, then what happens to the constructor function?

```
var data = {};
data.query = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
}
```

Also, why wouldn't we simply define it on the prototype instead?

```
Resource.prototype.query = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPg6A/

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's not exactly a duplicate in my opinion. The question is more about static vs non-static functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would define methods on the `prototype` only if they are meant to be called on specific instances. When methods are defined directly as constructor members, it's usually to mimic [*static*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods) methods.

Basically, when a method relates very closely to a *class*, but doesn't make much sense as an instance method, it can be implemented as a static method.

I think that you will agree with me that the second example makes more sense and if you do, you already understood the difference.

1-

```
var user = new User();

user.findUser('somequery').then(...);
```

2-

```
User.findUser('somequery').then(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and that makes sense, and is basically just a way of implementing static methods. My other question is on the way it is defined - how is it that we can do "Resource.query = function(xxx){}" when we have already defined "Resource" as a function? Wouldn't defining "Resource = {}; Resource.init = function(){}; Resource.query = function(){}" be better?

Comment: @DanTang No because you also want `Resource` to be a constructor function. If you do `Resource = {}`, how will you create new `Resource` instances? Functions are objects just like any other objects.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense! Can I ask one last question - I'm assuming "this" refers to the instance created from the constructor and thus static methods cannot reference it? So any functions defined on Resource can only access "static" variables on Resource (e.g. Resource.count) and variables on any outer scopes?

Comment: @DanTang Well, there's no real *static* concept in JS so you do not have the same restrictions some other languages may have for static members, however you are right that `this` will not point to an instance of `Resource` inside a *static* method, it would point to the `Resource` constructor. Besides this, there's technically nothing that prevents the code that runs inside `Resource.someMethod` to access whatever it wants to access. For example, if you declare a global variable `var r = new Resource();`,  nothing would prevent the code from accessing `r`.

Answer (score 1):

> I know functions are objects as well, and is this the equivalent of the following

There's nothing more to what you say. It's just like any other property on any other object.

> Also, why wouldn't we simply define it on the prototype instead?

The difference is that each object created using the constructor would then have that method in their prototype chain. This isn't true for properties defined on the constructor itself.

That is:

```
var Resource = function() {}
Resource.one = function() {
    console.log("one");
}
Resource.prototype.two = function() {
    console.log("two");
}

var r = new Resource();
r.two(); // => "two"
r.one(); // => TypeError: r.one is not a function
```

And:

```
Resource.one(); // => "one"
Resource.two(); // => TypeError: Resource.two is not a function
```

You might call `one` a *static* method, but the language doesn't treat it differently than any other function (unlike methods defined using, say, `static` in Java).